# How do I rewrite a fractional expression with a numerator that is a variable raised to an exponent...as an exponential?

Tags: fractions

For example:

$(x^2)/2 = x^w$

where w stands in for the value I'm trying to find.

Comment: Take $\log_x$ of both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Your power must be $2$ so the answer is $(\frac {x}{\sqrt 2})^2$